# Why does the console.log() tooltip show logarithm in Google Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ide, console.log, monaco-editor

I was working on a project in the Google Apps Scripts editor and used a `console.log` in my code. For some reason, instead of the typical console.log tooltip thing, I got a different and incorrect one. I've been unable to reproduce this. Is it an easter egg or something?

Normal tooltip:

[image: Correct console.log tooltip]

Tooltip I got:

[image: logarithm tooltip]

I've tried to reproduce this by putting the mouse in a bunch of different places in a console.log() line, including passing a number like this, but the tooltip's remained the normal one ever since. [image: Passing a number as the argument still results in the normal tooltip.]

(this still gives the normal tooltip)

Comment: You could recreate it, if you reassign console. `console=Math; console.log(11)`